# how to limit my mysql select characters

Tags: php, string

I am grabbing info from three rows in my table, and echoing one of them in a anchor tag.

How can I limit the amount of characters on the $title variable that are shown in the anchor tag.

Code:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $date = $row['date'];

    echo "<a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=$id"."\">$title</a> | ";
}

$thisID = $_GET['id'];

if(!isset($thisID)) {
    $thisID = 7;
}
```

Comment: Heads up, it is invalid to start an ID attribute with a number character. You should make it `$id= "link".$row["id"]` or some such, or it will cause issues with some scripts/browsers.

Comment: I prefer to use javascript to truncate my strings, based on the width of the parent element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
echo "<a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?id=$id" . "\">" . substr($title, 0, LENGTH) . "</a> | ";
```

Replace LENGTH with the length in characters to which you want to trim $title.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) in the query to return the leftmost set of characters from a column.

It's in the format of `LEFT(column, max_chars)`

```
define('MAXCHARS', '50');

$results = mysql_query("SELECT id, LEFT(title, ".MAXCHARS.") as truncated_title, 
                           date FROM news");
```

Now when you go to retrieve the column, aliased by `truncated_title` in this example, it will only contain at most however many characters as set in your `MAXCHARS` constant.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the first part of the string, or the last part, but if you do it would be better to provide an indication that something has been left out, by appending or prepending an *ellipsis* `...`